# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

while executing this SQL command:

```
select * 
from Person p 
where p.reference_no like (select referencenumber from Reference)
```

My `Reference` table has a column `referencenumber` as below

[image]

Comment: What about the error message is unclear?  This is one of the most descriptive error messages SQL Server can even throw at you...

Comment: Clearly your inner query returns more than 1 row.  `LIKE` only accept 1 row.

Comment: It's interesting that you used the `like` keyword.  What are you looking to achieve with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exists()` for this like so:

```
select * 
from Person p 
where exists (
  select 1
  from Reference r
  where p.reference_no like r.referencenumber 
  )
```

Also, why are you using `like` instead of `=` ? If you want to do a partial comparison, shouldn't it be `like '%'+r.referencenumber+'%'` ?

Comment: Minor note: `SELECT *` is fine in an `EXISTS` clause; there's no need to put in the artificial `1` as it won't speed things up.

Comment: @JeroenMostert There is no **runtime** performance difference between `select 1` and `select *` when using `exists()`. Although using `select 1` will avoid having to examine any unneeded metadata for that table during query compilation. 
[EXISTS Subqueries: SELECT 1 vs. SELECT * - Conor Cunningham](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/exists-subqueries-select-1-vs-select/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, although I wonder why the author thinks this implementation detail matters. I suppose if your table has an enormous number of columns, there might be an observable difference, and that alone could argue for `1` even if there's no quantifiable data.

Comment: @JeroenMostert As the "author" of that post is Conor Cunningham, I believe him. Google him. He is a Principal Software Architect at Microsoft on the SQL Server Query Processor Team. This kind of thing is literally his job. He is the guy behind the Query Optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

try something different

```
select * from Person p where 
           EXISTS  
             (select r.referencenumber from Reference r 
                      WHERE p.reference_no like r.referencenumber )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join based on your condition

```
select p.* 
from Person p 
inner join Reference r on p.reference_no like (r.referencenumber )
```

Or (due the fact your are not using wildchar ) you could use in

```
select * f
rom Person p 
where p.reference_no in  (select referencenumber from Reference)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this query using `exists`:

```
select p.*
from Person p
where exists (select 1
              from Reference r
              where p.reference_no like r.referencenumber
             );
```

However, if you are not using wildcards, then `in` suffices.